# algebra question..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions

If $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=\frac{2}{4^{x}+2}$

Find the value of $$f\left [ \frac{1}{11} \right ]+f\left [ \frac{2}{11} \right ]+ \cdots +f\left [ \frac{10}{11} \right ]$$

Comment: Assuming the OP means $f\left(\frac{1}{11}\right)$ and so on then the answer appears to be 5.  Which I must say is somewhat surprising.

Comment: There is a pairing.  $f\left(\frac{i}{11}\right)+f\left(\frac{11-i}{11}\right)=1$

Comment: Nice question, thanks!

Comment: Could any one explain to me, why exactly this question got downvoted? It is for sure that the OP was not really getting a way how to find it, so any hint to get the OP started would be highly appreciated. Much rather than placing a useless downvote.

Comment: @Pedro The reason why I, and I suspect others, downvoted is because no effort is shown. I indiscriminately downvote any and all problem statement questions, no matter how "interesting".

Comment: Just to say:  I upvoted it.  If you attack this problem by direct computation it looks quite strange.  I have no trouble believing that the OP simply hit a wall.  This doesn't look at all like a homework or test question to me.

Comment: @lulu I don't think being homework or not is relevant. I think the relevant part is effort shown. Just because it's not homework doesn't mean that the poster doesn't have to show effort.

Comment: @avid19  I hear you, but I feel differently.  A problem like this...it takes 10 seconds to get the result "5" on a calculator. But doing it that way it looks like a miracle.  It's really not clear how to proceed from there!  I get annoyed if people don't do obvious things in an attempt to solve a problem, but a stone wall is a stone wall.

Comment: Removed a bunch of off-topic comments, because the exchange was long enough to generate an automatic flag.

Answer (score 6):

Just to summarize,  there is a pairing here: $$x+y=1\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;f(x)+f(y)=1$$
This is readily verified by direct computation.
In this case that means we can combine the given terms in pairs, so the answer is 5.